# Limit records returned by range

Tags: sparql

Hi I have a particular sparql query which returns all my triples in a graph. This takes some time to run so I was wondering if I can limit the amount of triples and rerun the query everytime the user presses next on the interface ex: first he sees the first 10, then next 10 etc... Right now I am getting all the results and saving them and then traverse the results. Can I just get the first 10, next 10 etc..

Answer (score 1):

For a `SELECT` query, to get only the first ten rows:

```
SELECT ...
WHERE {
  ...
}
LIMIT 10
```

To get the next ten:

```
SELECT ...
WHERE {
  ...
}
OFFSET 10 LIMIT 10
```

For the next ten, increase the `OFFSET` to 20, and so on.

You say that your query is returning triples, so is it a `CONSTRUCT` query? `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` also work with `CONSTRUCT`, but the number of triples returned will depend on the number of triple patterns in the construct template.

**Edit:** When using `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`, on some SPARQL stores you will need to also use `ORDER BY ?x`, where `?x` is one of the query variables. This ensures a predictable order of the results.

Comment: `ORDER BY` is important when paging through a result set, else you may get some solution(s) multiple times and/or not get some solution(s) at all.

Comment: @TallTed Fair point. I've updated the answer. Note that it depends on the SPARQL processor. Some provide consistent results without `ORDER BY`, but including it is certainly the safe option.

Comment: "work properly" (as now in your answer) is a mischaracterization, and suggests that processors whose output row order varies are somehow malfunctioning. RDF stores (there is no such thing as a SPARQL store) do not have any mandate to store nor output data in any particular order. Likewise, SPARQL does not mandate any ordering of solutions *unless* there is an explicit `ORDER BY` clause. Some RDF stores and SPARQL processors *may* always deliver results with the same ordering, but this should (really, must) not be relied upon, especially but not only when changing from one processor to another.

Comment: Sure I'll fix it